# Can't return a value from UITextField to UILabel in UITableViewCell as subviews

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextfield, uilabel

I made a `UITextfield` to receive the data from user.

I want to convert a value from `UITextField` to `UILabel`.

I did it in simple `UIView`, which has only two object, `UITextField` and `UILabel`.

This is the code that works.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    let inputNumber = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 150.0, y: 100.0, width: 200.0, height: 50.0))
    let outputNumber = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 150.0, y: 200.0, width: 200.0, height: 50.0))
    let toolBarKeyBoard = UIToolbar()
    let flexibleSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: nil, action: #selector(donePressed))
    var result : String!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        calculatePrice()
    }

    func calculatePrice () {

        priceInputLabel.keyboardType = .numberPad
        priceInputLabel.clearButtonMode = .whileEditing

        self.view.addSubview(priceInputLabel)
        toolBarKeyBoard.sizeToFit()
        toolBarKeyBoard.setItems([flexibleSpace, doneButton], animated: false)
        priceInputLabel.inputAccessoryView = toolBarKeyBoard
    }

    @objc func donePressed() {
        view.endEditing(true)
        result = inputNumber.text!
        let convertedNumber = (result as NSString).doubleValue
        if Int(inputNumber.text!) == nil {
            outputNumber.text = String("Nil")
        } else {
            outputNumber.text = String(Int(convertedNumber * 0.85))
        }
    }
}
```

But in other case, down below, the problem is `UITextField` and `UILabel` are in the `UITableViewCell` as subviews.

I made a 3 swift files. 2 files are `UITableViewCell` subclasses, and 1 file is a `UITableView` class.

**1. FruitTableViewCell : UITableViewCell subclass**

```
class FruitTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {

    var fruitsTextField = UITextField()
    let toolBarKeyBoard = UIToolbar()
    let flexibleSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: nil, action: #selector(donePressed))
    var result : String!


    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        self.contentView.addSubview(fruitsTextField)

    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        fruitsTextField.frame = CGRect(x: 250, y: 7.5, width: 100, height: 30)
        fruitsTextField.textColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(242/255.0), green: CGFloat(56/255.0), blue: CGFloat(90/255.0), alpha: 1.0)
        fruitsTextField.keyboardType = .numberPad
        fruitsTextField.clearButtonMode = .whileEditing

    toolBarKeyBoard.sizeToFit()

    fruitsTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBarKeyBoard

    toolBarKeyBoard.setItems([flexibleSpace, doneButton], animated: false)


    }


    @objc func donePressed() {
        fruitTextField.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

**2. AnotherFruitTableViewCell : UITableViewCell subclass**

```
class AnotherFruitTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var fruitsTextLabel = UILabel()

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        self.contentView.addSubview(fruitsTextLabel)

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        fruitsTextLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown
        fruitsTextLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 250.0, y: 7.5, width: 100.0, height: 30.0)
    }
}
```

**3. TableViewController : UITableViewController class**

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    let fruitsComponents: [String] = ["Apple", "Banana", "Grape", "Pear"]

    let cellReuseidentifier = "cell"
    let anotherCellReuseidentifier = "anotherCell"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.register(FruitTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellReuseidentifier)
        tableView.register(AnotherFruitTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: anotherCellReuseidentifier)  
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {      
        return 1
    }

        override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {        
        return fruitsComponents.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseidentifier, for: indexPath) as! FruitTableViewCell
            cell.textLabel?.text = fruitsComponents[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: anotherCellReuseidentifier, for: indexPath) as! AnotherFruitTableViewCell
            cell.textLabel?.text = fruitsComponents[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        }
    }
}
```

The **fruitsTextField** and **fruitsTextLabel** is not in the same class like in the first example code.

So, I cannot call both instances and calculate a value in `ViewController` class. Of course, cannot return a calculated value.

And, I'm not sure I can return after touching a done button to get a value from `UITextField` to `UILabel`, because the cells which is the super view of subview(`UITextField` and `UILabel`) are reproduced. I'm confusing touching a done button occurs dequeueing cells again.

**How can I return a value from UITextField to UILabel in UITableViewCell?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to change some parameter of one cell based on action in another cell (actually the fact that these cells are of different classes is not important to that matter). ViewController will be in that case intermediary, so you need to make cells to communicate with ViewController. For communication between two objects one usually uses delegate or closure pattern.

In that case I would use closure. So, when you instantiate the cell with TextField ViewController tells Cell what to do when Done is pressed. To achieve that:

1. add `var didEntered: ((_ text: String)->())?` to `FruitTableViewCell`
2. add `didEntered?(fruitsTextField.text ?? "")` to `@objc func donePressed()`
3. add (the code updates the second row based on textfield value - just for a example)

   ```
   cell.didEntered = {text in
   self.fruitsComponents[1] = text
   self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.none)}
   ```

to `override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`

On the way I corrected some mistakes to make it work, so the complete code is below.

Upd 1

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    var fruitsComponents: [String] = ["Apple", "Banana", "Grape", "Pear"]
    var fruitsLabels: [String] = ["", "", "", ""]

    let cellReuseidentifier = "cell"
    let anotherCellReuseidentifier = "anotherCell"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.register(FruitTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellReuseidentifier)
        tableView.register(AnotherFruitTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: anotherCellReuseidentifier)
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return fruitsComponents.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseidentifier, for: indexPath) as! FruitTableViewCell
            cell.textLabel?.text = fruitsComponents[indexPath.row]
            cell.didEntered = {text in
                self.fruitsLabels = Array(repeating: text, count: 4)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: anotherCellReuseidentifier, for: indexPath) as! AnotherFruitTableViewCell
            cell.textLabel?.text = fruitsComponents[indexPath.row]
            cell.fruitsTextLabel.text = fruitsLabels[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        }


    }
}


class FruitTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {

    var fruitsTextField = UITextField()
    let toolBarKeyBoard = UIToolbar()
    let flexibleSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    var result : String!

    var didEntered: ((_ text: String)->())?


    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        self.contentView.addSubview(fruitsTextField)

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        fruitsTextField.frame = CGRect(x: 250, y: 7.5, width: 100, height: 30)
        fruitsTextField.backgroundColor = .yellow
        fruitsTextField.textColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(242/255.0), green: CGFloat(56/255.0), blue: CGFloat(90/255.0), alpha: 1.0)
        fruitsTextField.keyboardType = .numberPad
        fruitsTextField.clearButtonMode = .whileEditing

        toolBarKeyBoard.sizeToFit()

        fruitsTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBarKeyBoard
        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(donePressed))
        toolBarKeyBoard.setItems([flexibleSpace, doneButton], animated: false)


    }


    @objc func donePressed() {
        fruitsTextField.endEditing(true)
        didEntered?(fruitsTextField.text ?? "")
    }
}

class AnotherFruitTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var fruitsTextLabel = UILabel()

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.contentView.addSubview(fruitsTextLabel)

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        fruitsTextLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown
        fruitsTextLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 250.0, y: 7.5, width: 100.0, height: 30.0)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I tried with your code, but the result was not the same as I expected. When I input a number, it returns the number to the 'row1 title', not to 'row1 label', 'row2 label', 'row3 label'. Row1 label, Row2 label, Row3 label are still empty. But I understand that I need to make cells to communicate with ViewController!

Comment: @Hoo check updated answer (the complete code after Upd 1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UITextField` delegate methods to achieve this in your `TableViewController`.

In your `TableViewController` `cellForRowAt` method:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellReuseidentifier, for: indexPath) as! FruitTableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = fruitsComponents[indexPath.row] //"I am confused why it is here"
        cell.fruitsTextField.delegate = self
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: anotherCellReuseidentifier, for: indexPath) as! AnotherFruitTableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = fruitsComponents[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

Now add `UITextField` Delegate methods:

```
extension TableViewController : UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        print(textField.text!)

        let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: 1, section: 0)) as! AnotherFruitTableViewCell
        cell.textLabel.text = textField.text!
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.endEditing(true)
        return true
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help! But it doesn't work at all. Nothing has been changed. But 'extension' concept inspired me! Thanks!

Comment: I used this code in my project and it is working perfectly fine.